# OpenCV-2.4.8.2: imshow differs from imwrite

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV2.4.8.2 on Mac OS 10.9.5.
I have the following snippet of code:

```
static void compute_weights(const vector<Mat>& images, vector<Mat>& weights)
{
    weights.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        Mat image = images[i];
        Mat mask = Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_32F);
        int x_start = (i == 0) ? 0 : image.cols/2;
        int y_start = 0;
        int width = image.cols/2;
        int height = image.rows;
        Mat roi  = mask(Rect(x_start,y_start,width,height)); // Set Roi
        roi.setTo(1);
        weights.push_back(mask);
    }
}

static void blend(const vector<Mat>& inputImages, Mat& outputImage)
{
    int maxPyrIndex = 6;
    vector<Mat> weights;
    compute_weights(inputImages, weights);

    // Find the fused pyramid:
    vector<Mat> fused_pyramid;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputImages.size(); i++) {
        Mat image = inputImages[i];
        // Build Gaussian Pyramid for Weights
        vector<Mat> weight_gaussian_pyramid;
        buildPyramid(weights[i], weight_gaussian_pyramid, maxPyrIndex);

        // Build Laplacian Pyramid for original image
        Mat float_image;
        inputImages[i].convertTo(float_image, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255.0);
        vector<Mat> orig_guassian_pyramid;
        vector<Mat> orig_laplacian_pyramid;
        buildPyramid(float_image, orig_guassian_pyramid, maxPyrIndex);
        for (int j = 0; j < orig_guassian_pyramid.size() - 1; j++) {
            Mat sized_up;
            pyrUp(orig_guassian_pyramid[j+1], sized_up, Size(orig_guassian_pyramid[j].cols, orig_guassian_pyramid[j].rows));
            orig_laplacian_pyramid.push_back(orig_guassian_pyramid[j] - sized_up);
        }
        // Last Lapalcian layer is the same as the Gaussian layer
           orig_laplacian_pyramid.push_back(orig_guassian_pyramid[orig_guassian_pyramid.size()-1]);

        // Convolve laplacian original with guassian weights
        vector<Mat> convolved;
        for (int j = 0; j < maxPyrIndex + 1; j++) {
            // Create 3 channels for weight gaussian pyramid as well
            vector<Mat> gaussian_3d_vec;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                gaussian_3d_vec.push_back(weight_gaussian_pyramid[j]);
            }
            Mat gaussian_3d;
            merge(gaussian_3d_vec, gaussian_3d);

            //Mat convolved_result = weight_gaussian_pyramid[j].clone();
            Mat convolved_result = gaussian_3d.clone();

            multiply(gaussian_3d, orig_laplacian_pyramid[j], convolved_result);
            convolved.push_back(convolved_result);
        }

        if (i == 0) {
            fused_pyramid = convolved;
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxPyrIndex + 1; j++) {
                fused_pyramid[j] += convolved[j];
            }
        }
    }
    // Blending
    for (int i = (int)fused_pyramid.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        Mat sized_up;
        pyrUp(fused_pyramid[i], sized_up, Size(fused_pyramid[i-1].cols, fused_pyramid[i-1].rows));
        fused_pyramid[i-1] += sized_up;
    }

    Mat final_color_bgr;
    fused_pyramid[0].convertTo(final_color_bgr, CV_32F, 255);
    final_color_bgr.copyTo(outputImage);

    imshow("final", outputImage);
    waitKey(0);
    imwrite(outputImagePath, outputImage);
}
```

This code is doing some basic pyramid blending for 2 images. The key issues are related to imshow and imwrite in the last line. They gave me drastically different results. I apologize for displaying such a long/messy code, but I am afraid this difference is coming from some other parts of the code that can subsequently affect the imshow and imwrite.

The first image shows the result from imwrite and the second image shows the result from imshow, based on the code given. I'm quite confused about why this is the case.
[image: imwrite's result]
[image: imshow's result]

I also noticed that when I do these:

```
Mat float_image;
inputImages[i].convertTo(float_image, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255.0);
imshow("float image", float_image);
imshow("orig image", image);
```

They show exactly the same thing, that is they both show the same picture in the original rgb image (in image).

Comment: imshow for float values mean 0 = black and 1 = white so the totally white image has probably intensity values in a wrong scale.

Comment: Hi Micka, thanks for the response. But how come the imwrite is ok? You are correct about the scale. If I scale it by 1 near the end, the imshow is ok, but the imwrite is all black...

Comment: probably, imwrite and imshow use different assumptions about value range ;) what file extension do you write to? Maybe that file extension can even handle floats directly or just performs a type conversion without scaling the values (while imshow multiplies float values by 255!).

Comment: OpenCV doc says for imwrite: `Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function. If the format, depth or channel order is different, use Mat::convertTo() , and cvtColor() to convert it before saving` So if your values are scaled between 0 and 1 your imwrite will convert the values to be 0 or 1 in 8 bit channel values which is quite black. see doc: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite

Comment: Thank you Micka and the below post. It solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMWRITE functionality

By default, **imwrite**, converts the input image into **Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function**.
So whatever format you feed in for imwrite, it blindly converts into CV_8U with a range 0(black) - 255(white) in BGR format.

IMSHOW - problem

So when noticed your function, `fused_pyramid[0].convertTo(final_color_bgr, CV_32F, 255);` fused_pyramid is already under mat type 21 (floating point CV_32F). You tried to convert into floating point with a scale factor 255. This scaling factor 255 caused the problem @ imshow. Instead to visualize, you can directly feed in fused_pyramid without conversion as already it is scaled to floating point between 0.0(black) - 1.0(white).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Sriram. Your explanation was very insightful. I will never make this mistake again.