# OpenCV : imwrite changes the channels pixels values when saving

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm reading an image and doing some processing on the blue channel without changing the Red nor the green channels.

When i finished processing the blue channel, i merged back the three channels into one RGB image. and when i use imshow to view the channels, every thing is alright and i can see that the changes i've made only affect the Blue channel and they do not affect the red nor the green ones.

Up to this point every thing is alright !

But when i save the image using imwrite, the resulting image is slightly different, in that the changes made on the blue channel seem to get propagated to the red and green channels, it's like imwrite is doing some kind of mean between the 3 channels :

```
 image = imread('image.jpg', IMREAD_COLOR);
 split(image, channels);
// Create some changes on channels[0]

merge(channels, 3, image);
// Up to this point every thing is alright
imwrite("modified.jpg", image); // Image changes when written;
```

Is there any solution to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JPG is a lossy format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

> JPEG (/ˈdʒeɪpɛɡ/ JAY-peg)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a commonly used method of lossy
>   compression for digital images, particularly for those images produced
>   by digital photography. The degree of compression can be adjusted,
>   allowing a selectable tradeoff between storage size and image quality.
>   JPEG typically achieves 10:1 compression with little perceptible loss
>   in image quality.

Solution: Use a lossles Format like PNG to save your image.

Comment: That's the first thing i tried, but still, it is the same thing.

Comment: I dont think the problem is the lossy compression. I tried to do the same thing on Matlab and when i save the image, i can see that what ever changes i have made on one channel, the others doesn't get affected.
Also, i just found this post and i think it can be related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815299/opencv-2-4-8-2-imshow-differs-from-imwrite?rq=1

For now I've managed to do what i wanted, i'll try to look into it later. and post the right answer, or maybe in the meantime someone will find it.

Thank you man !

Comment: Hi @AllaouaBenchikh, if you tried to use PNG why didn't you wrote about it in your Question? It is always helpful if you show what you tried when asking a question! You could try to save it as *bmp. If this doesn't work double check that the merged channels are correct so that we can locate the error. How did you managed to do what you want? If it is a solution (even if it is a bad one) to your problem, please share it with us to help future readers.

Comment: Man thanks for the answer. Was struggling for this for days.